# Getting Error, But the package is installed

Tags: python, django

[image]I am trying to set a little report system up on the system to allow admin to produce reports as Csv documents.

I found Django-import-export installed it changed my INSTALLED_APPS, everything worked. If there was no module names import-export im guessing putting it into INSTALLED_APPS would have given me a error before this one so i dont understand why im getting this error.

Like the documnetation suggests i'm adding

```
from import_export import resources
```

Into admin.py but i get an error each time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/vagrant/twm/component/admin.py", line 11, in <module>
    from import_export import *
ImportError: No module named import_export**strong text**
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: What have you tried and checked? Is the package visible when checking in `pip freeze` ?

Comment: @Nrzonline Hey thanks for replying, I cant seem to find it within pip freeze but when i do Sudo pip install i get Requirment already satisfied ill print screen the results and put them on the question, thank you again.

Comment: Installing packages as root is never a great idea in my opinion. You might consider using a virtual environment. For the most of our projects we use vagrant as well, and run an install script for the first vagrant up to setup the requirements with virtualenv

Comment: I am using vagrant, arnt i? I'm lost again, i though i was using a ve. I hate this framework.

sorry just fustrated, thanks for replying again.

Comment: Don't get too frustrated, it's a part of the learning process. I'm sure it's safe to say that every developer experienced that feeling. Vagrant is indeed a virtual environment for your OS/machine. However, virtualenv is specially for containing packages. Installing packages as root gave me problems in the past before. Storing them into virtualenv saved me some trouble. I'll write a small guide to get you started with virtualenv in vagrant.

Comment: @Nrzonline That would be so helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, installing packages is not a good idea in my opinion.
You might consider using virtualenv within your vagrant. This most likely will solve your issues.

1) **Write your current requirements to a file**

When using the virtualenv, we probably want the same packages which you
have now. Write the current requirements to a file called requirements.txt by typing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (in your project root)

2) **Edit your Vagrantfile**

Open your Vagrantfile and after

`config.vm.box = "<yourbox>"`

add

`config.vm.provision :shell, path: "install.sh"`

We will create install.sh on the next step. This install script will be executed every time you perform the `vagrant up` command.

3) **Create your install.sh file**

```
echo "--- Installing Virtual env ---"
mkdir /virtualenv &>/dev/null
virtualenv /virtualenv &>/dev/null
source /virtualenv/bin/activate &>/dev/null

chown vagrant:vagrant /virtualenv -R &>/dev/null

echo "--- Installing PIP ---"
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py &>/dev/null
python get-pip.py &>/dev/null
rm get-pip.py &>/dev/null

echo "--- Installing Django dependencies ---"
pip install -r requirements.txt &>/dev/null
```

4) **destroy and up your vagrant**

Destroying the current vagrant will make you lose any adjustments you made in your vagrant (not in your files). You can add any adjustments to your install.sh so it will be configured on vagrant up. If you are sure you are ready to destroy your vagrant, type `vagrant destroy` followed by `vagrant up`

When you upped your vagrant, you will see `(virtualenv)` in front of your prompt. Package loading and installing will now be done in the virtualenv.